# How to map arraytype to Jsonb[] in Postgresql?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure ADF returns `ERROR: column "data" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[] Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression` when I try to map ArrayType to JSONB[] in postgresql.
How to I convert or cast to JSONB[] from ADF?

Thanks

***update***
[image]

The array contains JSON elements.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure data factory there is not any data type for array of Json even you have Json values in your array it will treat it as a array of string.

So, the workaround to obtain tor desired result is to alter the respective column in the precopy or post copy script respectively and then copy the values.

**PRECOPY:**

```
alter table journal2 alter column Name type text[] using Name::text[]
```

**POSTCOPY:**

```
alter table journal2 alter column Name type jsonb[] using Name::jsonb[]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is it corectly understood that i change the datatype of the column before sinking, and then after change it back again?

Comment: Yes, because ADF will only treat it as array of string